# Error: invalid operands of types 'int' and 'float*' to binary operator '/'

Tags: c++

```
Error: invalid operands of types 'int' and 'float*' to binary'operator/'
int *average = new int((num) / data);
```

showing up for this line of code.
Why so?

```
float *data;
int num;
int mode;
double average, median;

cout << "How many students were surveyed?  ";
cin >> num;
data = makeArray(num);

float getAverage(float *data, int num)
{
    int *average = new int((data) / num);
    return *average;
}
```

Comment: It means that you are trying to divide a number by a pointer (`data`). Which is meaningless.

Comment: can you show your code where how num and data has been declared in your program.

Comment: float *studentData;  studentData = makeArray(num);

Comment: And num is just a cin integer

Comment: I've edited your title to make it more meaningful. Your original title "Error: What does this error mean?" doesn't tell us anything useful.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the declarations; don't assume everyone is going to read the comments. All the information needed to answer your question should be in the question itself. And I don't know what "just a cin integer" means; show the actual *declaration* of `num`.

Comment: @KeithThompson I think i edited to what you asked.

Comment: You are leaking memory in your getAverage function now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you are comparing two incompatible types together. One of `num` and `data` is an `int`, and the other is a `float*`.  Depending upon the behavior you want you will want to

1. Dereference the pointer, as in `*x` for whichever `x` is the pointer
   2a.  You will want to cast the `int` to a `float` for `floating point division`, where result is converted back to an `int`
   2b. You will want to cast the `float` to an `int`, for `integer division`, which will then be converted back to an `int`.

**Update**
Since you updated your code I'll point out a bigger problem; you are now leaking memory.

I would suggest you consider instead returning your integer by value and potentially pass by reference or constant reference and avoid pointers entirely here, but more over I would suggest some symmetry in your input parameters as well as const correctness:

```
//your code:
float getAverage( float *data, int sum )
{    
    //data is a float* and needs to be de-ref'd and casted to int for float but isnt
    int *average = new int( (data) / num );
    //note that now average is a pointer to a newly constructed int that will never be free'd
    return *average;  //because you return it here, where the value will then be implicily converted to a float and be mostly worthless.
}

// In both suggestions I will use symmetric types, I will not introduce dynamic memory and I will use floating point division for maximal accuracy.

// Suggestion one use Const References
float getAverage( const float &data, const int &num)
{
    float result = data / (float) num;
    return result;
}

// Suggestion two use pointers to constants
float getAverage( const float *data, const int *num )
{
    float result = (*data) / float(*num);
    return result;
}

// Suggestion three pass by value since primitives are cheap
float getAverage( float data, int num)
{
    float result = data / (float) num;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: the num value is a int and data is a float in the function.

Comment: yes but i though if i was to '*data' instead of just 'data' that just dereferences  it.

Comment: Wait that fixed it but i'm confused as to why.

Comment: @user3507443 That's correct but you hadn't dereferenced the pointer in the code you provided originally, hence it said `float *`

Comment: float getAverage(float *data, int numStudents)
{
 int *average = new int((*data) / numStudents);

 return *average;
}  sorry i cant figure out how to make this display as code. this is what i changed it to, and it seems to be working.

Comment: That's different than what you had posted above :-)

Comment: Guessing the memory leak is whats causing the program to not make it past where i call that function.

Comment: Not necessarily, with a leak like that it shouldn't impact anything until you run out of memory I would think. I would suggest using a debugger and or some print statements to see exactly where and why you are 'not making it past'